# Multiply every value of a series with each other in pine script

Tags: pine-script

I'm using pine script and I want to multiply every value of a series with each other. Let's say I have a series with the following values:

```
a = [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

start by multipling the first two values

```
2 * 3 = 6
```

then it should multiply the third element with the previous product

```
6 * 4 = 24
```

closing with

```
24 * 5 = 120
```

Creating a new series:

```
prod = [2, 6, 24, 120]
```

I tried to multiply the 0 bar value with the previous bar value but this is wrong because I want the  product of all previous values.

```
a_value := valuewhen(condition, a, 0)
a_previous_value := valuewhen(condition, a, 1)
prod := a_value * a_previous_value
```

Is there a simple way to get this result?

Comment: A series in Pine is built as the bars progress. Maybe if you could explain what you intend to accomplish with this, there's a change we can provide a solution.

Comment: Yes, that's right. The numbers above are just an example to explain the problem. In my real case I'm plotting multiple series that are the result of previous calculations. Getting the product of each series is a way for me to compare them. I want to calculate the final value of each series in order to choose one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it, but the numbers become very large, very fast.

```
//@version=4
study("Prod", overlay=true)

var float prod = na
var float a    = na

a := bar_index % 10
prod := nz(prod[1],1) * (a==0?1:a)

plot(prod)
```